# How to change value of a variable from a file?

Tags: php, file

I need to replace a line in a file.php.

I need to replace a value of a variable of a file.php, yet I can get the desired line, take the value of the variable but do not know how to replace the whole line.

Example:

```
<?php

    $archive = file('Library/config/PaymentConfig.php'); // transforms the content into an array where each line is a position
    $valueLine = $archive[10]; // $environment = 'production';

    function getEnvironment($valueLine){
        $removecharacters = array('$environment = ', "'", ';');
        return str_replace($removecharacters, '', urldecode($valueLine)); // returns only the value of the variable
    }

    if (getEnvironment($valueLine) == $myValue) { // $myValue = production or sandbox   
        // Here I need to replace the line
        // For $environment = 'production'; or $environment = 'sandbox';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Whilst this is certainly possible, i doubt its a good idea. Editing source code with code is error prone. Why not just read the variable from a txtfile/database in file.php, then you can edit the txtfile/database value instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer 2

```
<?php
    $archive = "Library/config/PaymentConfig.php";
    $search = "PaymentConfig['environment']";
    $arrayArchive = file($archive);
    $position = 0;

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arrayArchive); $i++){      
        if(strpos($arrayArchive[$i],$search) && (strpos($arrayArchive[$i],'production') || strpos($arrayArchive[$i],'sandbox'))){
            $fullLine = $arrayArchive[$i]; // $PaymentConfig['environment'] = "production"; // production, sandbox
            $position = $i;     

            if(strpos($fullLine, '"production"') == true){
                $environment = '"production"';
            } else if(strpos($fullLine, '"sandbox"') == true){
                $environment = '"sandbox"';
            }
        }
    }

    echo $environment; // current environment
    $newEnvironment = '"sandbox"'; // or $newEnvironment = '"production"';

    if ($environment == $myValue) { // $myValue = production or sandbox  
        $arrayArchive[$position] = str_replace($environment, $newEnvironment, $fullLine);
        file_put_contents($archive, implode("", $arrayArchive));    
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ready let the best possible code 100% automatic without bugs what do you think now? @user574632

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, i would suggest editing file.php to get the value from a txtfile/database.
Using a text file:

```
//file.php
$environment = file_get_contents('environment.txt');
```

Then in your code, you can change the value in the text file:

```
$environment = 'production';
file_put_contents('environment.txt', $environment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer

```
if (getEnvironment($valueLine) == $myValue) { // $myValue = production or sandbox   
    $archive[10] = '$environment = "sandbox";' . "\n";
    file_put_contents('Library/config/PaymentConfig.php', implode("", $archive));
}
```

Comment: It may be correct as of now, but when someone adds a comment or just a single carriage return to file.php, anywhere above line 9, your entire website blows up.

Comment: is fixed, the library does not change if change is just change the line containing what must change

Comment: Fine as long as you are the only person who will ever work on this code, and provided you can remember all these little hacks in 12 months time when you want to change something.